# ¿Cómo cambiar el Texture Type de una imagen .png a Sprite a través de un script en Unity?

Tags: unity, unity3d

Estoy usando Unity y tengo muchas imagenes en la carpeta Resource. Dichas imagenes las voy guardando utilizando mi servidor hecho en nodejs y MySQL.

Lo que necesito hacer es que al leer esas imagenes, les cambie el Texture Type a "Sprite" a través de un script( por defecto viene configurado en "Default"), ya que es necesario que tengan un Texture Type "Sprite" para poder poner la imagen en un canvas.

Se que se puede hacer utilizando el inspector de Unity pero necesito hacerlo con un script, ya que no sé que imagenes van a estar ni que cantidad.

Saludos.

[image: Detalles de las opciones de la Imagen en la interfaz]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que comentas puedes utilizar AssetPostprocessor que permite ejecutar scripts antes o despues de importar assets, en tu caso OnPreprocessTexture debería funcionar:

```
using UnityEditor;

class TextureTypeToSprite : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;
    }
}
```

Debes de tener en cuenta que con este script cualquier textura exportada cambiará su TextureImporterType a Sprite por lo que sería recomendable poner alguna condición para diferenciar cuales son las texturas que deseas cambiar, algo así como:

```
using UnityEditor;

class TextureTypeToSprite : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        if (assetPath.Contains("_icon"))
        {
            TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
            textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

hará que solo se cambie para las texturas que contengan "_icon" en algún lugar de su ruta (nombre de archivo o carpeta).